# How do I find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{xy + 1} -1}{x + y}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Compute $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{xy + 1} -1}{x + y}$$

If you look at the graph of the function, it suggests that the limit does not exist. In fact, the limit DOES NOT exist. But how do I prove that?

When I approach the function from either $x$ or $y$-axis, the limit is equal to $0$. It is also equal to $0$ for every line (except for $x=-y$) passing through the origin.

I tried to approach $0$ on a parabola $y=x^2-x$ but the limit was again $0$.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I did a mistake when calculating the limit as I approached $0$ on the parabola $y=x^2-x$ the result should be $1$ for that limit proving that the limit does not exist.

Comment: If you don't share some of your own thoughts on this, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: This will get you started: $\frac {\sqrt {xy + 1}-1}{x+y} = \frac {xy}{x+y(\sqrt {xy+1}+1)}\\ \lim_\limits{x,y\to0,0}\frac{xy}{x+y}\lim_\limits{x,y\to 0,0} \frac {1}{\sqrt{xy+1} +1}$

Comment: Sorry, I added the approaches I tried to solve this limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP, it appears that you have analyzed the limit along straight-line and parabolic trajectories.

Let's analyze the case for which the limit is approached along the path $y=-x+x^\alpha$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{-x^2+x^{1+\alpha}}{x^\alpha}=x-\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-2}}\tag1$$

What can you conclude now?

---

For the record, if the limit is approached along the path $y=-x+x^2$, then with $\alpha=2$ in $(1)$, we find

$$\frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{-x^2+x^3}{x^2}=x-1\to -1\ne 0$$

from which we can conclude the limit fails to exist.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I made a mistake in my calculations. I see it now.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?